# mo / po translation files does not seem to work

Tags: translation

I have a theme that was bought from [themefuse](http://themefuse.com/wp-themes-shop/travel-wordpress-theme/) and they say it supports localisation using a plugin called [CodeStyling Localization](http://www.code-styling.de/english/development/wordpress-plugin-codestyling-localization-en)

However even though I make the necessary steps to translate strings in the theme, the translated texts do not appear in the frontend.

The steps I have taken:

1. installing plugin
2. scan the theme
3. translate a few words
4. build "mo" file from plugin menu
5. empty cache + refresh ... no result

Any ideas?

Comment: Desired language is setted correctly in `wp_config.php`? If so it's impossible to answer without look at the code.

Comment: I created a [php script](https://github.com/cleversonferreira/wordpress-po-translate) to translate PO files, I'm still working on it, maybe it can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `wp-config.php` file and see if your language is defined :

```
 define('WPLANG', 'your_language');
```

You could add this if you're still stuck:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','wpse_110727_translate_theme');
function wpse_110727_translate_theme() {
     load_theme_textdomain( 'textdomain', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
     $locale = get_locale();
     $locale_file = get_template_directory() . "/languages/$locale.php";

         if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) ) require_once( $locale_file );
 }
```

Just put the translation files into a repertory called `/languages/` and upload all files in the root of your theme.

See if it works now. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** 'textdomain' is the word used in all translation strings :

`_e('some content','textdomain');`

Comment: The default language was not set in wp-confing thank you!